# XSLT 2.0: select some @class names but not others

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have documents with indent names in a class, such as:  `<div class="if">` and `<div class="i1 note">`, and so on. (the indent classes are: if, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6).

The non-indent CSS selectors vary widely. But the indent CSS selector names are consistent.

Objective: I'd like to store the non-indent classes in a variable for future use.

Here's the direction I was going in, without success:

```
<xsl:variable name="indent-names" 
     select="'if i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6'"/>

<xsl:variable name="non-indent-classes" 
     select="replace(@class,$indent-names,'')"/>
```

Suggestions?  I'm thinking a `<xsl:analyze-string select="@class" regex=" .... ">` is the way to go. No success yet.

**UPDATE**

Based on Martin's answer, I did this:

```
<xsl:variable name="indent-names" 
    select="'if i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6'"/>

<xsl:variable name="non-indent-classes" 
    select="tokenize(@class, ' ')[not(. = tokenize($indent-names, ' '))]"/>
```

Works great. I must become more familiar with `tokenize()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `tokenize(@class, ' ')[not(. = tokenize($indent-names, ' '))]`. Obviously it is more efficient to do the inner tokenize once and store it in a variable `<xsl:variable name="names" select="tokenize($indent-names, ' ')"/>`, then use that variable `tokenize(@class, ' ')[not(. = $names)]`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll experiment with that. 2.0 has so many tools to work with strings...